# What is Java Regex to match number then space then 3 alphabet char?

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate the about of money with the currency Unit.

```
100 USD : valid
1.11 USD : not valid
1,12 USD : not valid
12 US : not valid
```

So the valid string is "the number then space then 3 alphabet char".

```
text.matches("^\\d+ [a-zA-Z]{3}*$")
```

I got error: 
 `Exception caught: Dangling meta character '*' near index 16 
^\d+ [a-zA-Z]{3}*$`

So how to fix it?

Comment: Why do you have the `*`?

Comment: '*' means "0 or more of the previous", and applying it to `{3}` makes no sense, hence the error.

Comment: thax I fixed: ^\\d+ [a-zA-Z]{3}$ is the correct one right?

Answer (score 1):

i fixed obmitting * then it is fine:

```
text.matches("^\\d+ [a-zA-Z]{3}$")
```

Comment: If yoq want to take the validation further, instead of matching `[a-zA-Z]` you could match `(USD|ARS|AED|...)`